# How to integrate $\int \cos{x}\sec{\frac{x}{a}} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration

Although *Wolfram|Alpha* gives a solution to this integral, it is in the form of complex/imaginary functions, and so I preferred if someone could find it in the form of "real" functions.

I've tried approaching it by interchanging the integral sign and summation of the Taylor series of $\cos{x}\sec{\frac{x}{a}}$, but in any way the interchanging most likely isn't possible... Also, I'm trying to solve via using the Laplace transform or Fourier's or even Fourier series —not done yet. Maybe using the imaginary definitions of these two trigonometric functions could help too.

To take into account, the intervals of $a$ and $x$ are: $0<a<1$ and $0<x<\frac{\pi}{2}$.

Comment: Where does this problem come from? What have you tried?

Comment: Also, do we know anything about $a$? Is it an integer? A rational number? An arbitrary real number?

Comment: I've updated the question: hope it helps.

Comment: So you're trying to find$$\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\cos x\sec bx\,\mathrm dx$$Where $1<b<\infty$

Comment: No, the antiderivative.

Comment: @JoanSGF But you're integrating $\cos x\sec\frac xa$ between $x=0$ and $x=\pi/2$

Comment: It is its interval of use: in my case, values of x outside that range do not mean anything.

Comment: Sorry for the typo's. Now, it is clean (I hope). Cheers :-)

Comment: [One antiderivative is](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+of+cos%28x%29*sec%28x%2Fa%29) $\frac{ia}{a^2-1}\sum_\pm(1\mp a)e^{i(1\pm a)x/a}F(1,\,\frac{1\pm a}{2};\,\frac{3\pm a}{2};\;-e^{2ix/a})$ [with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypergeometric_function) $F:={}_2F_1$.

Comment: Yes, I mentioned it in the post. At least it looked really similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\frac 1 a$ is an integer, let $b=\frac 1 a$
$$\int \cos (x) \sec \left(\frac{x}{a}\right)\,dx=\int \cos (x) \sec \left(b x\right)\,dx=$$ Using  Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind
$$\cos(by)=T_b(\cos (y))$$
$$\int \frac {\cos(x)}{\cos(b x)}\,dy=-\int \frac{t}{T_b(t)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}} \qquad\text{where} \qquad t=\cos(y)$$

If $r_k$ are the roots of $T_b(t)$
$$\int \frac{t}{T_b(t)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=2^{1-b}\int \frac{t}{\prod_{k=1}^b(t-r_k)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$$ Using partial fraction decomposition, you then face the problem of
$$I_k=\int \frac{dt}{(t-r_k)\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac{\log (r-t)-\log \left(1-rt+\sqrt{1-r^2} \sqrt{1-t^2}\right)}{\sqrt{1-r^2}}$$ Summing and simplifying, this will give mixtures of logarithms, arctangent and hyperbolic arctangent functions.

**Edit**

We can now consider the cases where $b$ is odd or even since $T_b(t)$ is a polynomial of degree $b$. The most interesting case is even $b$ which simplfies further using $t^2=u$. For example, for $b=6$,

$$\int \frac{t}{T_6(t)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=\frac 12\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{1-u} \left(32 u^3-48 u^2+18 u-1\right)}$$ and
$$\int \frac{du}{ (u-r)\sqrt{1-u}}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{r-1}}\tan ^{-1}\left(\frac{\sqrt{1-u}}{\sqrt{r-1}}\right)$$

Comment: Since it is for $\frac{1}{a}$ as an integer, can I directly surround it by a ceiling or floor function to make the integral valid or straightforward for this condition and preocupy later for its decimal values?

Comment: @JoanSGF. If $a$ is not an integer, you must use numerical integration of the formula given by WA

Comment: Actually, there is one that rounds it: $\lfloor \frac{1}{a} \rceil$

Comment: But is it $a$ or $\frac{1}{a}$?

Comment: @JoanSGF. Did you follow the steps and in particular the first change of variable ?

Comment: Actually, excuse my ingenuity, but I don't get the first one. Like how did you go from $x$ to $y$ and where did the $a$ in front of the 2nd integral come from

Comment: @JoanSGF. $x=ay$ whic makes $dx=a dy$

Comment: Yes but if you do this substitution wouldn't the fraction be $\frac{\cos{ay}}{\cos{y}}$ ?

Comment: @JoanSGF. Sorry for the typo. I shall fix it

Comment: Thank you. Does this mean the rest is not correct or only the writing of that fraction?

Answer (score 0):

Even $\int \cos(x)/\cos(7x)\,dx$ involves solving a polynomial equation of degree $6$.
Substitute $t=\cos(x)$:
$$
\int \!{\frac {\cos \left( x \right) }{\cos \left( 7\,x \right) }}
\,{\rm d}x=-\int \!{\frac {1}{64\,{t}^{6}-112\,{t}^{4}+56\,{t}^{2}-7}{
\frac {1}{\sqrt {1-t^2}}}}
\,{\rm d}t
$$

Comment: I don't get it. Isn't $a$ between $0$ and $1$?

Comment: Here $a=1/7$ is between $0$ and $1$.

Comment: @JoanSGF You have $\frac 1a$ listed in the question where $0<a<1$. When $a=\frac 17$, then $\frac 1a=7$

Comment: My bad, I had a stroke.

Comment: What's the substitution then? Because it says $t-\cos{x}$.

Comment: I've seen you've edited it, thanks